# I want to use progress Indicator aura component and it should change according to lead stage field. Please suggest relevant approach

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

```html
<lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="3" type="path" variant="base">
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.stage.Lead_Stage__c }" var="stage">
        <lightning:progressStep label="{! stage.label }" value="{! stage.value }"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to control "currentStep" variable from js. Easiest solution is to make an Apex call and get return stage of that record and assign that variable to "currentStep".

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getStage(Id recordId){
    Lead ld = [select Id, Stage from Lead where Id =: recordId];
    return ld.Stage;
}
```

Store ld.Stage in variable in js file and bind that property with "currentStep".